# What is the name of default DUAL table in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I need to query Netezza Data Warehouse. I've been told not to use any table for the moment. I had checked for the existence of `DUAL` table and found over the net like,- there is a `_v_dual` table as like Oracle `DUAL`.

Is the information is correct that I can query with `_v_dual`. Is this available by default for all Netezza database or is it something else I have to do in order bring up the `DUAL` functionality for Netezza Data Warehouse Querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use _v_dual at all.  Simply perform a SELECT with no FROM clause.  For example:

```
select current_timestamp, UPPER('abc');
      TIMESTAMP      | UPPER 
---------------------+-------
 2016-06-04 02:25:20 | ABC
(1 row)
```

That being said, _v_dual was added as a comfort to Oracle users, and is available by default.